# Need to create a SepaMandate for street walkers?

Tags: api, civisepa, recurring-contributions

Business logic:
Customer sends out street walkers who recruit recurring donors on the streets with forms in their hands (or on their tablets). They need to create SEPA mandate reference numbers in advance.
Customer has implemented the basic CiviSepa and CiviBanking extensions.
I am going to add this functionality to the CiviSepa extension (see https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.sepa/issues/271)

To generate these required Sepa mandate reference codes I thought I could use the API SepaMandate with the create action. This API requires an entity table and id, which I do not have yet. Should I still use the API or should I set up a separate table for the generated references and use those to create a mandate once the recurring contribution is added?

Comment: Erik - The term "street walkers" has a very different meaning in the US than the way you use it.

Comment: Thanks @Sarah I will ask no further :-) Do you have the right word for me?

Comment: I would suggest "sidewalk donor recruiters". Then again, it depends on your customer, and what the "donation" is meant to cover. :-)

Comment: As said before, I think I will leave the subject well alone :-) Thanks @Sarah!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To generate these required Sepa mandate reference codes I thought I
>   could use the API SepaMandate with the create action. This API
>   requires an entity table and id, which I do not have yet.

There's currently two API calls for creating a SEPA mandate: `SepaMandate.create` and `SepaMandate.createfull`. The first one requires indeed a contribution/recurring_contribution to exist, the second one will create both in one go. Both of them take a `reference` parameter with an externally generated mandate reference number. If this is not set, a new reference number will be generated. Does that answer your question?

Comment: To be complete, I have used the API SepaMandate createfull with parameters: type=RCUR, frequence_unit=month, frequence_unit=1, amount=12.5, start_date=01-06-2015. This generates a recurring contribution AND a SEPA Mandate.