# Is there a simple way to import recurring SEPA mandates that have been processed outside CiviCRM previously and should now be managed using CiviSEPA?

Tags: import, civisepa

In the [CiviSEPA Setup Instructions](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/CiviSEPA+Setup+Instructions) there is a section regarding importing SEPA mandates, but instead of an answer there is a question... (similar to the one I am asking.)

I have been checking the database tables and *Contribute* options and unless I have missed something, there is no way to import the contributions along with the mandates. That is, using the *Import contributions* option will populate the `civicrm_contribution` table, but not the `civicrm_contribution_recur` table which stores the details of the recurring transactions.

There is also the question of populating the `civicrm_sdd_*` tables which are specific to the **CiviSEPA** extension.

I don't intend to have all the history of the mandates I want to import, but at least a working mandate list that may be used to generate future mandates.

I suppose that I could create a script to inject the data in the proper tables or through the API, but would like to know if someone has tried something easier or has something to start with.

**UPDATE**

I have found this question that also mentions `SepaMandate` and `createfull`: [Need to create a SepaMandate for street walkers?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2193/need-to-create-a-sepamandate-for-street-walkers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed there is not a standard importer for SEPA mandates. I have migrated SEPA mandates a few times and I use the `SepaMandate createfull` API. That will create the mandate and the recurring contribution.

If you then want to import actual payments you should fill the column `contribution_recur_id` to ensure they are linked to the mandate.

Comment: Using the API sound like a good idea, thanks! For the second part you mean using the field `contribution_recur_id` of the `civicrm_contribution` table to point to the `id` of the right register of the `civicrm_contribution_recur` table? How do you propose to do the import of the payments?

Comment: Indeed, and using the Contribution create API.